# Bacteria can produce sulphuric acid with pH values of <1 Could a more complex organism use them?

Tags: science-based, creature-design, dragons, biochemistry

Previously, I asked about the plausibility of a sulphuric acid dragon. As it turns out, the answer was right on Wikipedia, namely [a. thiooxidans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acidithiobacillus_thiooxidans) and the [snottie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snottite)

> Snottites are highly acidic biofilms (pH 0-1) that form on the walls and ceilings of hydrogen sulfide-rich caves where sulfide-rich springs gas H2S into the cave air. The snottite microbial communities have very low species diversity and are predominantly composed of sulfur-oxidizing microorganisms. Sulfide oxidation produces sulfuric acid, which dissolves the limestone walls of the cave. **Microcrystalline gypsum precipitates as a corrosion residue that eventually limits pH buffering by the underlying limestone and enables the development of extremely acidic wall surfaces**. A. thiooxidans is known to inhabit these biofilms. Snottite morphology and distribution within caves depends on the availability of carbon, nitrogen, and energy substrates in the atmosphere. Snottite formations are generally milky in color, suspended vertically from cave ceilings and walls, and have a phlegm-like consistency (hence the name).

[image]

Sulphuric acid fits the characteristics of dragon breath weapon the best. After all, not only does this thing cause chemical burns, its dilution is also highly exothermic, meaning that if you get sprayed in the face with it, first you get chemical burns, THEN second-degree, regular burns. [you can imagine what it would feel like.](https://youtu.be/aopdD9Cu-So?t=27)

Apparently, there are microbes that produce this beast, which are also content with living in pH<1 environments.

So, the question is if there are bacteria that could survive in this environment, **would it be possible to adapt the stomach-lining (the mucous membrane) of my dragons to be able to withstand it as well?**

Note: Today, I found out that bacteria of the genus *[Picrophilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picrophilus)* are able to withstand pHs of -0.06, and die above pHs of 4.

I also found out that [acidophiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acidophile#Mechanisms_of_adaptation_to_acidic_environments) resist their environment by building acidic residue into their proteins.

Comment: The dilution effect will only produce that kind of heat if the acid is very concentrated -- bio-sourced acids typically aren't.  Your stomach acid is nearly as acidic as sulfuric, but its concentration is fairly low -- which is why vomit doesn't produce skin burns and scar your mouth membranes.  Sulfuric acid at the strength in a car battery (30% by weight) barely prickles the skin, rather than burning it away as the concentrated form would.

Comment: @ZeissIkon That's why I linked the snottie. Other bacteria, that produce sulphuric acid can achieve at around 3-1 pH, while a. thiooxidans so insanely strong, it goes below 1 and is also used for bioleaching. Also, the 0-1 pH is the pH of the snottie itself.

Comment: Better recheck your chemistry.  pH doesn't depend (much) on concentration, but on the actual species producing the acidity or alkalinity.  Sodium carbonate solution at 0.1 m has the same pH as at 1 m strength -- but it won't stay that alkaline *as long* when you start titrating an acid into it.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon we are talking about sulfuric acid here. pH can easily go below 0.

Answer (score 3):

Your own stomach has a PH of about 1.5-3.5 (your skin has a PH of 4.7 for comparisons) so not only is it possible, you'd starve to death if it wasn't possible because your stomach wouldn't work as designed.

The most acidic compound in the human stomach is hydrochloric acid.  In addition to the mucus membrane, gastric acids are regulated by secreation of sodium bicarbonate, which neutralizes the acid before it enters the intestines.  It's entirely possible your dragon could have a similar system.

Finally, there's a lot of little bacteria that live in your stomach and this is a good thing as they will compete for resources from other bacteria that will make you sick.

Comment: vultures and buzzards can pull off PHs of 1.1 and crocodiles can produce gastric acid faster than any animal ever recorded, https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/full/10.1086/524150

Comment: @John:  Thank you.  I figured humans weren't the most acidic, though our omnivore nature does help with boosting it up.  I figure buzzards as Carion eaters want to make sure microbes that help with decay are not getting into the system.  I also think there are some medical conditions where human gastric acids will reach lower pHs but I'm no expert.  The first rule of biology is every other rule has an exception.